# Export preview in Gimp

Tags: gimp

Is there some solution for Gimp to preview exported result image when i change some export settings like quality for jpg or amount colors for gif? Like in Photoshop Export interface.

Answer (score 1):

For JPG just tick the "Show preview in image window" box in the export dialog.

Comment: This solution is just for JPG ?

Comment: Yes. No solution for GIF, but IMHO you have better work in color-indexed mode anyway, then change when you export on-the fly can be much deeper than just "quality".